# Default ember template with specific model record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js

I've scouring for a bit, but can't find an answer to this. I've got an Ember route on a Rails app, and I would like one of the model records to be displayed by default when visiting the URL (right now, a user needs to click on a specific link to retrieve the data).

For example, when visiting /albums, I would like /albums/38 to be active and visible without forcing a redirect. Is that possible?

Thanks

```
App.Router.map ->
@resource 'albums', path: '/', ->
    @resource 'album', path: '/:id'

App.AlbumsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: -> @store.find 'album'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an 'index' route for the 'albums' resource and redirect to the 'album' route with the first model.  The index route will only be hit when you hit just the `albums` resource, and not when you hit deeper (aka not when you hit `/albums/1`).

```
App.AlbumsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: -> @store.find 'album'

App.AlbumsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: ->
       album = this.modelFor('albums').get 'firstObject' # This can be whatever...
       this.transitionTo('album', album) if Ember.isEmpty(album) is no
```